# MDX (calculations) - count all clients accounts

Tags: mdx, olap, cube, olap-cube

I would like to count all clients accounts in my cube. I have created new calculation and I wrote a query in MDX langugage like:

```
COUNT( 
 [Client].[IdClient]
)
```

but when I would like to know how many accounts have, I always get '1' value instead e.g. '6000'.
This is my first time with MDX and OLAP Cubes.
What I supposed to do to get correct value?

Comment: If a user filters on the client dimension would you want your calc to only return the number of clients selected by the user? Or do you always want it to return the total number of clients? What if they filter on another dimension like Date? Should it only count clients that have data for that date range?

Comment: @GregGalloway I would like to know how many man and woman clients I have. In my client dimension is information about sex: male or female.

But I would like to know also total number of clients.

Comment: I must display count of clients split by age group too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
COUNT( 
 EXISTING [Client].[IdClient].[IdClient].Members
)
```

If you aren't happy with the performance of that then delete the calculated measure and replace it with a measure group built on the Client table. Build a Count measure.